# Excel - Power Query TrimStart With condition

Tags: excel, powerquery

I want to trim 2 chars. if it’s Start with “20”

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlmmE.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test whether the text starts with "20", and if so, then return the text after "20":

```
if Text.StartsWith(Example, "20") then Text.AfterDelimiter(Example,"20") else Example
```

**Edited answer:**

A similar approach, but this step transforms values in a table column. Change `Source` and `MyValue` references to suit.

```
= Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{"MyValue", each Number.From(let x = Number.ToText(_) in if Text.Start(x,2) = "20" then Text.AfterDelimiter(x,"20") else x), type number}})
```

Comment: I apologized for showing unclear example, I have attached the sample image to the question, Thank you very much for your answered

Comment: Similar solution applies - you can transform the column - answer edited.

Answer (score 0):

I started with a basic text file that looks like this ...

```
Example
20456 208899 123 366420
20324 535435 654 533454
852 929492 583 283832
```

... and for transparency and to show you how I got through it, all steps are outlined below.  I suspect this could be done in a more efficient manner but it does the job.

##### Step 1

[image: Step 1]

##### Step 2

[image: Step 2]

##### Step 3

[image: Step 3]

```
= Table.AddColumn(
#"Promoted Headers", 
"Result", 
each if Text.StartsWith([Example], "20") then Text.Middle([Example], 2) else [Example])
```

##### Step 4

[image: Step 4]

##### Step 5 (Result)

[image: Step 5]

Comment: I apologized for showing unclear example, I have attached the sample image to the question, Thank you very much for your answered

Comment: @AnousoneLuagnhkot, all good.  I've added another answer which may help.  You can use of the ones you have on offer, they all work.

Comment: I've already got my solution million thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

- Split your string by the `space` into a List.
- Transform the list by checking each element to see if it starts with `20`

eg:  As an added column:

```
   #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", 
        each 
            Text.Combine(
                List.Transform(
                    Text.Split([Column1]," "), 
                        each 
                            if Text.StartsWith(_,"20") 
                            then Text.Middle(_,2) 
                            else _)," ")
            )
```

[image]

***Original and Results***
[image]

***Note:***
*If you don't want to add a column, you can **transform** the existing column with the same algorithm, but you need to use the Advanced Editor to enter the code*:

```
    trim20 = Table.TransformColumns(#"Previous Step", {"Column1", (c)=> 
        Text.Combine(
            List.Transform(Text.Split(c," "), 
                each if Text.StartsWith(_,"20") then Text.Middle(_,2) else _)," ")})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing it on sheet directly, it's very straight forward.

[image: Formula]

`=IF(LEFT(A1,2) = "20", MID(A1, 3, 1000), A1)`